# How do I apply the same style to a dynamically created element as that of another element with the same classname in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My **HTML** code:

```
<div class="side-bar">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item"><a id="item1" href="#">Dynamically create submenu here</a></div>
        <div class="item">
            <a id="item2" href="#">Already created submenu here</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <a href="#" class="sub-item">Sub item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="sub-item">Sub item 2</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My **CSS**:

```
.side-bar .menu .item .sub-menu{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    display: none;
}

.side-bar .menu .item .sub-menu a{
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

My **Jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#item2').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

---

This code works perfectly fine, when I click the `#item2` anchor tag, the sub menu opens and closes perfectly. I want to use this same style to a sub menu that I created dynamically and attached to `#item1`. This is my code:

```
function get_all_the_values(){
    return $.ajax({
            url: '/php_script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"input": "get values"}
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#item1').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).next('.sub-menu').is(':visible')){
            (async()=>{
                let response = await get_all_the_values();
                const arr = JSON.parse(response);
                let elem = document.createElement("div");
                elem.className="sub-menu";
                elem.id="id1";
                for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
                    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
                    anchor.className="sub-item";
                    anchor.href="#";
                    anchor.innerText = arr[i];
                    elem.appendChild(anchor);
                }
                document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].appendChild(elem);
                $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideDown();
              });
         }
         else{
             document.getElementById("id1").remove();
             $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideUp();
         }
     });
});
```

I have checked my `response` and it's fetching the correct values from my server. I have given the same class name (`sub-menu` and `sub-item` to the submenu and subitems respectively) so that it follows the same style that is written in my `css`.

But it doesn't work as expected. When I click the `#item1` anchor, the sub menu doesn't show, even when the `console` shows that it's created.

Why is that? The `classname` is the same, so it should follow the same styles. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: More specific for jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I don't see any issue here. You code works in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5ynwa7gr/

Comment: @CodeThing no it doesn't, did you check there is a difference in both when you hide the sub-items again?

Comment: So that's a different question. The op here asked specifically about sub menu not showing up. There is no mention about style when you hide it.

Comment: There was a mistake in copying my code, what I want is to actually fetch the values from my `php` server and then make a `sub-menu` containing those values. I've updated my post, please check

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with the question title then

Comment: Have you checked the browser developer tools? You can right click your page and select "Inspect" from the menu (or most browsers hit F12). It has a detailed view which style rule was chosen. If you see a conflict you might have a [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem. You might have styled for an ID or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of the dynamically added `.sub-menu` is different from that of the static one because you are using different methods to show/hide them.

The static one uses [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) - which has that nice in/out animation. The dynamic one uses `document.getElementById("id1").remove()` - which immediately removes it from the DOM without a nice animation. :(

What I would do is use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach the same sliding behavior to all `.sub-menu` elements.

```
$('.menu').on('click', '.item', function() {
  $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

The only remaining piece to take care of is to ensure we `slideToggle()` the dynamically created menu immediately once we fetch the data and create it. I have altered your code a little bit. The result is:

```
$('#item1').click(async function() {
  if ($(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').length === 0) {
    const response = await get_all_the_values();
    const arr = JSON.parse(response);
    let elem = document.createElement("div");
      
    elem.className = "sub-menu";
    elem.id = "id1";
      
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var anchor = document.createElement("a");
      
      anchor.className = "sub-item";
      anchor.href = "#";
      anchor.innerText = arr[i];
      elem.appendChild(anchor);
    }
      
    $(this).parent().append(elem);
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/h7y1eouj/) for reference.